# How can I set the layout of a layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

View -> Layout0 -> Layout1 -> ?

Layout0's whole purpose is to tell Layout1 which layout to use. How can I do this?

In some views I want my form next to a menu column and in others I only want the form by itself. When without the menu I need to skip a layout in the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this with a view bag variable which is picked up by the layout.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/layout/_form.cshtml";
    ViewBag.ParentLayout = "_layout2.cshtml";
}

@RenderBody()
```

And then in _form.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = ViewBag.ParentLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a similar question to [Change Layout(Master Page) of view in ASP.NET MVC without recreate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516116/change-layoutmaster-page-of-view-in-asp-net-mvc-without-recreate-it)

If the question is really one of "How do I choose my layout based on [X]," that post might help you. Consult the view _ViewStart.cshtml, which is tasked with assigning a Layout to begin with. Then, using razor, choose layouts based on the calling controller or some other condition.

You can also assign the layout from a given controller when returning a view:

```
...
return View("ViewName", "_LayoutPage", modelName);
```

Comment: That last snippet would not set the correct layout. I've added an answer.